# "even after six months of spread" or "even after a six month spread"

Tags: phrase-usage

I've made up the two similar sentences below.

(1a) Even **after six months of spread**, the virus still remained unknown to scientists.

(1b) Even **after a six month spread**, the virus still remained unknown to scientists.

Which phrase in bold is correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary:
during first **few months of marriage**
a **six-month** contract

it seems if you add a **hyphen** between six and month, turning it into adjective, both sentences are correct.